# How to check mouse pointer is crossing browser plane (mouse exits the webpage)?

Tags: javascript, analytics

Please check out bounceexchange.com and the 'free instant demo'.

How can javascript be used to check the user is about to cross the browser plane with accuracy? This functionality would be useful to incorporate to my own website.   What I would like to know is how to track the mouse leaving the website.

Any help given would be much appreciated.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {console.log(e.pageX);});`. `e.pageX` will be `-1` when "stepping out" of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When the mouse leave the page or is clicked the 'x' button?

this is the first case:

```
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).mouseleave(function() {
        alert('stay plz');
    });
</script>
```

this is the second:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
    function WindowCloseHanlder()
    {
        window.alert('My Window is reloading');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Teemu Just tusted with ie 8, ff 21, opera 12.15, safari 5.1 and chrome 27.0 , mouseleave works for me in every browser..

Comment: ?!!! Can you save your test at http://jsfiddle.net ? I couldn't get `onmouseleave` to work with this... Or is it only available in jQuery for all browsers?

Comment: @Teemu have you included <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> ?

http://jsfiddle.net/249m9/

Comment: when the mouse leaves the page

Comment: what does leaves the page exactly mean. what action make you leave the page? just to be clear

Comment: when you move the mouse off the page. similar to how is used in the link: http://bounceexchange.com/pub/preview?client_id=201&url=bbc.com#back

Comment: move the mouse off the page (towards the browser pane)

Comment: And my first example doesn't work for you?  jsfiddle.net/249m9
It made the same thing, just use a global var to show the message only the fist time.
Do you also need the element which appear?


Please remember to add this:


<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>;